# Add year and/or month to the single event permalink in Wordpress "The Events Calendar"?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and "The Events Calendar" plug-in, and it gives each 'event' a permalink URL like /event/

That works, and I can change /event/ to whatever word I'd like, but when I have events like 'First Day of School', it makes me realize that what I'd really like is to add more information to the slug like '/event/2012/' or '/event/2012/09/' ... but within 'The Events Calendar' plug-in I can't figure out how I would do that or if it is even possible.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without using the plugin, can you amend your permalink structure in `Settings > Permalinks`

Maybe a custom structure you could use would be:

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%
```

Not sure how Events Manager is registered, you may need to place something in front of the structure

```
/%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%
```